# how to invoke form submit from javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html, timer

i am developing a online test website using PHP. i have set time limit for the test and i have used javascript to run the timer. what i want to do is to submit the form with answers when the time runs out. please help me to do it.

Comment: Note that using javascript for time validation won't work when a user has javascript disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var oneMinute = 60 * 1000,

submitTest = function () {
    document.getElementById("testForm").submit();
};

setTimeout(submitTest, oneMinute);
```